# Geolocation code working on desktop browsers but not on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My Google Map javascript code displays on desktop browser but not on mobile devices (not apple nor android). I know there are other questions similar to this one, I have tried the answers and no luck.
This is what I have tried:
I have called the getLocation function when the page has loaded. Then I initialize the map... no luck.

The error message I get is: error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE I get this message on every mobile device.

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", getLocation);
});

function getLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initMap, showError);
 }
 else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
 }
}

function initMap(tipoUser,userId,locations) {
 var icn="img/mechanic.png";
 var meIcn="img/me.png";

 directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  polylineOptions: {
  strokeColor: "red"
 }
});

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: 13,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.529773,-113.509387), 
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var i;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

$.each(locations, function(index, element) {  
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(element.longitud),    parseFloat(element.latitud)),
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.529773,-113.509387), 
  map: map,
  icon: icn,
  optimized: false
});
markers.push(marker); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', (function(marker, i) {                 
      watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
        lat = position.coords["latitude"];
        lng = position.coords["longitude"];
        markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},    map: map, icon:meIcn});           
      });

  return function() {     
    var distinationOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);  
    var destinationMarker = parseFloat(element.longitud) + ',' + '' +  parseFloat(element.latitud);
    infowindow.setContent(element.datos);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,  distinationOrigin, destinationMarker, infowindow);
  }
})(marker, i)); 
});

var checkPositions=setInterval(function(){ 
    while(markers.length){
        markers.pop().setMap(null);
    }


$.post('codigo/getLatLngFromDB.php', {who:tipoUser, userId:userId},      function(data){
    miJson=$.parseJSON(data);  
    watchMecs(userId,miJson);
    return false;
}); 
},60000);
}


function showError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("An unkown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: are location-services allowed in the specific browser´s? Have you checked the settings? If you would implement the getLocation function with the correct error handler´s, you would know what the problem is

Comment: Which browsers have you tested on a desktop?  And is your site `https`?

Comment: Your initMap function has the wrong signature to be a callback function for `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.  The posted code doesn't work for me even in desktop browsers.  Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Hi, thanks for your comment, I think you are right because as you can see I already solved the problem but still I am having issues, would you please show me how to set the right signature to the callback function for `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` ?

Comment: sideroxylon, I have tested on every known commercial browser, and yes my site is https

Comment: If you solved this question, then you need to ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solved it,

I had to go to the google developer site where keys are and add my domain name in many ways such as *.example.com *.example.com/ www.example.com www.example.com/* etc... that was the only way I could get to see the map showing on mobiles.

Thank you all for your comments